# Ender 3 Pro goes to one location on the bed and extrudes

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

I'm having trouble with my customized Ender 3 Pro. It's running an SKR v1.3 board with Marlin and OctoPrint on a Raspberry Pi 4. My problem is that sometimes when the printer goes to print, instead of drawing the first line to prime the nozzle, it goes to max X and Y and extrudes what appears to be the full amount of plastic that would be extruded in a layer. It then proceeds to execute its Z-moves like it would in a print, without changing X and Y. The result is a lot of plastic being extruded very quickly in one location. There's also a BLTouch sensor on the machine. I've also come across the error while it's in the middle of a print. It'll just stop what it's doing on a layer, go to max X and Y and start extruding and raising the Z-axis.

What I've tried to solve it:

- Turned it off and on again. This sometimes works. After leaving the printer off for a while, I start the print again with the same exact G-code, and the print works perfectly. Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't.
- Looked around in the Marlin firmware for errors. The Ender is running a version of Marlin I customized from the stock version to fit my hardware.

Comment: what's your start G-code? Have you checked if your endstops are in the MIN or in the MAX endstop pins?

Comment: How complex would it be for you to go back to a stock setup? That could at-least help you identify if the bug is hardware or software related (albeit it sounds software to me).